# Glassfish - Unable to update http port. Server shut down

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a problem with Glassfish 4 that occurs when I try to start it.
I have searched for this error only but I haven't found a similar case.
Here's the error log:

```
Unable to update http port. Server shut down.
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException:
Could not save to L/Servers/GlassFish 4 at localhost [myDomain].server.
```

But even though I've had this error, in Eclipse, the state of the Glassfish server is said to [Started, Republish] and I can access the Glassfish admin console.

Have any idea about what is going on there ?

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old question but the issue still happens on Eclipse 2019-09 so here's what I found and a workaround for it.

It's caused by hitting the `Switch Location` button on server properties

[image]

That will remove this element on `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/servers.xml`

```
<server auto-publish-setting="1" 
  glassfish.adminserverportnumber="4948" 
  glassfish.debugport="4909"
  glassfish.serverportnumber="4980" 
  glassfish.domainpath="/home/luis.munoz/projects/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain-test/domain-test-1" 
  hostname="localhost"
  id="GlassFish 3.1 [domain-test-1]" 
  name="GlassFish 3.1 [domain-test-1]" 
  runtime-id="GlassFish 3.1" 
  server-type="glassfish.server" 
  server-type-id="glassfish.server"
  start-timeout="240" stop-timeout="240" timestamp="0" />
```

`runtime-id` must match the one in `.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs`

**WORKAROUND**:

- Close Eclipse since `servers.xml` is cached.
- Add the element back on `servers.xml` to fix the error. Change details as needed.
- Start Eclipse

Server properties will show `Location: [workspace metadata]` again and the error message will not appear when starting Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

are you using 8080 port ?

ensure that no other processes are listening, if yes - kill em.

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
```

Comment: Hi @Drahos, thanks for answering. I'm using the 8080 port indeed, and there are no other processes listening on that port.